# SignTransaction with a private key and sendTransaction with an other account

Tags: web3js, wallets

is it possible to sign a transaction with Alice private key and send the signed transaction using Bob account ?

Comment: The operation `sending a signed transaction using an account` is equivalent to the operation `signing a transaction using the account's private key and sending it`. So no, what your asking is impossible by definition.

Comment: Unless i understood this wrong, you want an account ( Alice ) to sign a transaction, then someone else will post it to the blockchain on their behalf. That is possible if Alice signs a transaction, you take the raw data and send it to a blockchain node. Keep in mind that alice can do it herself and she is going to be the one that needs gas for the processing, and the poster   is just a relay. See sendRawTransaction.

Comment: There is also the possibility of having Alice sign a payload that is then added into a transaction by Bob, which is then posted by Bob, and a smart contract that validates alice's signing of that payload using ecRecover. Really depends on what you're trying to do with this.

Comment: Very cool! and let's say that alice is an old system that it doesn't has a web3 library and it want to sign the the transaction with a standard crypto lib, is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, you don't need web3, just take the raw transaction and send it as an rpc call to the Ethereum node, like this https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendrawtransaction

Comment: I meant to sign the transaction do I need web3 ?